# Issue with QThreadPool: fail to finish all the task?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have the following code:

```
/////////////////////////////////
//main.cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "myserver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyServer server;
    server.startServer();

    return a.exec();
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//myserver.cpp
#include "myserver.h"
#include "myrunnable.h"

MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent)
{
    pool = new QThreadPool(this);
    pool->setMaxThreadCount(10);
}

void MyServer::startServer()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        MyRunnable *task = new MyRunnable();
        task->setAutoDelete(true);
        pool->start(task);
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//myrunnable.cpp
#include "myrunnable.h"
#include <qdebug.h>
MyRunnable::MyRunnable()
{
}

void MyRunnable::run()
{
    qDebug() << "Run";
}
/////////////////////////////////
// MyServer.h

#ifndef MYSERVER_H
#define MYSERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QDebug>

class MyServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyServer(QObject *parent = 0);
    void startServer();

protected:

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QThreadPool *pool;
};

#endif // MYSERVER_H
/////////////////////////////////
// myrunnable.h

#ifndef MYRUNNABLE_H
#define MYRUNNABLE_H

#include <QRunnable>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDebug>


class MyRunnable : public QRunnable
{
public:
    MyRunnable();

protected:
    void run();

public:
    qintptr socketDescriptor;

};

#endif // MYRUNNABLE_H

///////////////////////////
//project file
QT       += core
QT       += network
QT       -= gui

TARGET = QTcpServerThreadPool
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    myserver.cpp \
    myrunnable.cpp

HEADERS += \
    myserver.h \
    myrunnable.h
```

I run my code hoping by calling the `startServer` function it will give me 11 Run print on the screen. But it never did so. It printed out some Run on the screen but never all of them.

And the program even crash sometimes due to the stackoverflow. I checked the call stack and it is caused by some strange QMutex recursive.

So I assumed there must be some serious threading related issue with my code due the usage of QThreadPool and QRunnable.
But I cannot figure out what it is even after reading the Qt's Docs...

Comment: And where is `"myrunnable.h"` and `"myserver.h"`?

Comment: Please see the edited question, I have added the header files.

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Comment: What version of Qt do you use and what compiler?

Comment: Did you get all 11 Run print out? I am using Qt 5.4.1 with visual studio 2013. I use qmake -tp vc xxxxx.pro to create the project file for vs 2013

Comment: I use the same configuration and I get 11 Run printed

Comment: But I don't use Visual Studio, I use qtcreator.

Comment: Did you compile Qt by yourself or download it from Qt site?

Comment: I download the binary from Qt site... Strange.

Comment: Do you have any warning messages during compilation process?

Comment: No. BTW, I also attached my .pro file at the end, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I can't see any problem with your code or with project file. If you get stack overflow, it is possible that you use binaries and libraries of Qt, that do not correspond to headers that you use. May be you have some Qt installed on your system?

Comment: Yes. I have Qt 5.4.1 Qt 5.3 and Qt 4.8.6 all on my computer. But I never set system path for the Qt's dll.

Comment: So check whether you use proper Qt binaries. You can print all information you need using `message()` function in .pro file. Check path to headers and binaries.

Comment: Also check what dll loaded when you start application, from 5.3 or from Qt 5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be misdiagnosed, it is likely that the problem lies with `QDebug` and not `QThreadPool`

Substitute the following code

```
void MyRunnable::run()
{
    QTextStream cout(stdout, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    cout << "Run" << endl;
}
```